# Convert iterator to int

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

```
int i;
vector<string> names;
string s = "penny";
names.push_back(s);
i = find(names.begin(), names.end(), s);
cout << i;
```

I'm trying to find index of an element in vector. It's ok with `iterators`, but I want it as `int`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) for this.

```
i = std::distance( names.begin(), std::find( names.begin(), names.end(), s ) );
```

You will probably want to check that your index isn't out of bounds, though.

```
if( i == names.size() )
    // index out of bounds!
```

It's probably clearer to do this with the iterator before using std::distance, though.

```
std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = std::find( names.begin(), names.end(), s );

if( it == names.end() )
     // not found - abort!

// otherwise...
i = std::distance( names.begin(), it );
```

Answer (score 5):

```
std::vector<string>::iterator it = std::find(names.begin(), names.end(), s);
if (it != names.end()) {
    std::cout << std::distance(names.begin(), it);
} else {
    // ... not found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
i = (find( names.begin(), names.end(), s ) - names.begin());
```

Edit:
Although you should consider using vector::size_type instead of an int.

Comment: @thetux4: It shouldn't do. When you subtract two iterators you should get a difference type which for `std::vector<std::string>::iterator` is an integer type.

Comment: Yes i know ;) That's why you should use my line instead of yours. find() returns an iterator and subtracting names.begin() from that iterator yoields a vector<string>::size_type. (an unsigned integer type - probably something like unsinged long)

Comment: Hey! if you replace your line "i = ..." with my line it works perfectly well.

Comment: The results of iterator subtraction is *not* a `size_type`, it's a `difference_type`, by default `ptrdiff_t`, and always a signed type.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions that I am making about your code:

```
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
```

If my assumptions are correct, then you can [`find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) the [`distance`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/distance/) between the beginning of the [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) and the [`iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/iterator/) (essentially the index into the `vector` at which you can find such element):

```
using std::distance;
```

Like so...

```
vector<string>::iterator i = find(names.begin(), names.end(), s);
if (i != names.end())
{
    cout << "Index " << std::distance(names.begin(), i);
}
else
{
    cout << s << "not found";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just dereference your iterator

```
int i = *name;
```